# Should I ask if it makes sense to apply?

Tags: interviewing, communication, applications, qualification

I am planning to apply at the flight school of a big European airline.
Over the past two years I gained my private pilot license (PPL) and I am not really happy at my current job and would much rather persue a career as a pilot.

However from another fellow pilot I heard that said flight school rejected a candidate that had their PPL in the second to last step in the interviewing process with the comment that they'd rather shape their pilots on their own. As the interviewing process takes up to 3 days to that point and it would cost me some to get to the interviews and stay there.

In 7 days the flightschool has a livechat information event which I signed up for, just to gather more detailed information and experiences from others.

Now I wonder: *Should I ask if it makes sense for me to apply with already having a PPL?*

I am afraid that it makes me look partially uninterested or leaves a bad impression in some other way.

Comment: The way I heard it was that most airline pilots tend to be interested in flying so do have a ppl...

Comment: This would be a good question on Aviation in a slightly different form.

Comment: I would also suggest to ask this question in a slight different way on [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/). There's a good number of commercial pilots that can better address your concerns.

Comment: My goodness - a question not about programming!  Booyah

Comment: @Blrfl In which form? "Is there a difference if I apply for an airline flight school already having a PPL?"? The answer is likely going to be "depends on airline and flight school". Further a lot of airline pilots are not educated by an airline owned fligth school but rather built their career themselves by going through the process of getting their full license in a privately owned flight school. So I am not sure if it makes sense to ask that question. If you have another idea on how to ask, I would very much appreciate the input!

Comment: ^ Same thingy to @tweray; new comment because I can only ping one person per comment ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *I heard that said flight school rejected a candidate that had their PPL in the second to last step in the interviewing process with the comment that they'd rather shape their pilots on their own.[...]*

I have no knowledge about the aviation industry, but from a plain sight, it appears to me that the company is saying: *"Because you got college degree or previous work experience, we will not hire you, we want to shape our own engineers."*

Well, unless there is some condition in the job offer that makes the applicants with PPL ineligible, I believe in this case, the reason is not actually a valid one. It appears to what seems like a *canned response* behind a rejection. They just used the argument to dismiss that candidate, without providing a proper reason.

However, if you're in doubt, you can always ask. Just make it plain and simple:

> *"Is there a difference in the application process if I already have the PPL?"*

If they are not allowing candidates with PPL, you'll get to know right away. There's no problem asking, and if they really have restriction for hiring pilots with PPL, they'll also be actually happy that both the parties will save some time and effort.

Comment: @FooTheBar Yep, sounds better, let me actually use that.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was,

> Should I ask if it makes sense for me to apply with already having a PPL?

Regardless of if we're talking jobs being an airline pilot or any other career path, it pays to understand the requirements for the job position, and how the hiring team is making their decisions. Since you have an opportunity to ask questions in the upcoming chat, you should definitely take advantage.

However, there's a fine line in how you phrase such questions. You don't want to come off with a tone of,

> should I bother applying because of X (which might be problematic)?

Doing so will cast a negative tone to your question. And, perhaps more importantly, it really limits the information you'll receive in response - at worst, you'll just get a yes or no answer. Better to use the question to get **as many details as you can** about how they view qualifications (both negatively and positively). As such, you could phrase your question along the lines of,

> Can you help me understand what qualifications or prior experience influence the hiring process?

Or maybe,

> Are there specific qualifications/certifications that help you make a decision about a candidate's fitness for this role?

Or, given the specific nature of the feedback that other candidate received, maybe:

> How do you balance training and experience a new pilot may have received elsewhere against the training that you expect to provide them once they're hired?

These questions will all hopefully prompt a discussion, or at least a paragraph or sentence answer, instead of just "No, don't bother applying." And getting that additional information may certainly be valuable for you in this case.

All that said, I want to address the specific scenario your fellow candidate has described to you. It's likely that the answer he received was not the main reason - or at least, definitely not the only reason - he was rejected. Something like the fact that he had his PPL was probably readily visible at the beginning of the hiring process, if that was a strict reason for disqualification there would have been absolutely no reason for the airline to waste hours or days interviewing the candidate before rejecting them.